# testing data pattern in excel file

Tags: c#, string, excel, pattern-matching

I have an excel sheet that comes in the following format

```
06:07:00   06:07:00

           some data
           some data
           some data

06:15:00   06:15:00

           some data
           some data
           some data
```

I'm reading column A as a string and want to test for the right pattern for e.g.: 00:00:00

Then using column A access it's group of data. Here is what I have done:

```
string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

        Excel.Range range = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;

        for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
             str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt,1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
               if((str != null) &&(str == "00:00:00") ) // this test for the pattern does'nt work properly

                   listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                       }
```

The test above for the pattern isn't working as intended it goes and skips all the rows even the rows with the correct format (e.g.: 06:07:00). Now once this is done how do I access the group "some data"

EDIT:

```
 for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
              str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt,1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                if ((str != null) && (boxNumberRegex.Match(str).Success))
                {                  

                    str2 = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt+2,2] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                    listBox2.Items.Add(str2);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                }

         }
```

With this I'm able to get the 1 line of some data now how do I reiterate to get all of the some date under one time (e.g. 06:07:00)

EDIT2:

```
 for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
                   str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt,1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                if ((str != null) && (boxNumberRegex.Match(str).Success))
                {        
              int val = rCnt+2;

                    str2 = (string)(range.Cells[val, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                    listBox2.Items.Add(str2);
                     do{
                         val++;
                         str2 = (string)(range.Cells[val, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                         if (str2 != null)
                            listBox2.Items.Add(str2);
                       }while(str2 != null);

                    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regular expression

```
Regex rx = new Regex("^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$");
if (rx.Match(str).Success)
{
listBox1.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Comment: Please check my EDIT, I'm able to get the first line. How do I get all of it

Comment: If you don't want repeat entries in `ListBox` then check using following `if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(str)) listBox1.Items.Add(str);`

Comment: thanks for you help, i got it working please see edit2